# Implementing ActionListener in a JButton child

Tags: java, swing, awt

What are the downsides to this kind of hack, except the inability to listen to many buttons with one listener:

```
   public class Activator<E> extends JButton implements ActionListener {

        protected E controller;

        public Activator( String label, E controller ) {
            super( label );
            this.addActionListener( this );
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            return;
        }

    }
```

A button is instantiated by:

```
    this.buttons = new LinkedHashMap<String, JButton>();

    this.buttons.put( "create",
        new Activator<MainMenu>( "Create new definition", this ) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                this.controller.createDefinition();
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see the advantage of this extra class, which can easily be replaced by a simple method.

```
this.buttons.put( "create", 
    createButton( "Create new definition", new ActionListener(){...} );

public JButton createButton( String label, ActionListener actionListener ){
  JButton button = new JButton( label );
  button.addActionListener ( actionListener );
  return button;
}
```

This also needs an anonymous class, just like in your code, but avoids the extra (weird) class (weird in the sense that the button is an action listener, which is not supposed to be attached to anything else).

Comment: My main misunderstanding was that "ActionListener is just an interface, thus cannot be instantiated". I should have checked whether it is possible to create an anonymous ActionListener. Thank you!

Comment: @vrode: The example does not _instantiate_ the interface; it creates an anonymous inner class that _implements_ the interface.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious downside I can see is that you've got an extra class and more code than you'd have if you just created the button and added the listener to it. There is still an inline listener implementation when using the `Activator`, so is it doing anything useful (even with multiple buttons using this pattern)? Do you need the `Activator` class at all?